# Multiple textboxes with selection or focus to follow in a multiline textBox?

Tags: vb.net, textbox, selection

I have a problem with a multiline TextBox text box, which when searching for a character string, stays with its first focus on the word in the first location, but still continues to select the other words by not selecting them not !

Here is my code:

```
If testArray(p) / 2987 >= dub + (1787 / 2987) And testArray(p) / 2987 < dub + 1 Then
                Main.TextBox31.Focus()
                Main.TextBox31.SelectionStart = Main.TextBox31.Text.IndexOf(Me.TextBox1.Text)
                Main.TextBox31.SelectionLength = Me.TextBox1.TextLength
                Main.TextBox31.ScrollToCaret()
                MsgBox("oui16")
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
            End If
```

The first line gives me the position of the search bytes. The TextBox31 control is the multiline control, in which I have the search bytes in the testArray (p) array. The TextBox1 control gives me the string I'm looking for.

PS:

[image]

Comment: *"continues to select the other words by not selecting them not"*. You're going to have to try again and this time make sense. Please specify exactly what you expect to happen and what actually happens. If screenshots would help to clarify, provide them too.

Comment: I can't send you a screenshot! Am I stupid? I beg your pardon. In fact, in the multiline zone, the focus is only on the first word, whereas the word exists six times in the same TextBox a little further, but I cannot fix these with a focus! Maybe with a do ... loop until?

Comment: So you're actually saying that you want to highlight multiple instances of the same text? If so then you can't use a TextBox because you can only select one section of text. Use a RichTextBox and then you can highlight multiple sections of text by colouring them rather than selecting them.

Comment: Ok jmcilhinney, I got it, I will have a RichTextBox when I upgrade the app next time. For now, I'll stay that way. Thank you again for the help you give me. Claude.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve something like this with a listbox, it might translate over to textboxes too?

```
                    Dim rect As Rectangle
                    Dim bruh As New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(120, 0, 0, 225))
                    Dim gfx As Graphics = ListBox1.CreateGraphics
                    gfx.FillRectangle(bruh, rect)
```

Comment: No relation to the question (plus, `.CreateGraphics()` refers to a *volatile* DC).